# Music Library will not load in Ubuntu One Music app for Android

Tags: ubuntu-one, android

I keep getting the error message "Didn't understand the response from the server" when I open the music library tab in the Ubuntu One Music app for Android.  I can do random play or random albums from the main page, but I can't view my whole library.  I am using a Motorola Droid 2.

Answer (score 2):

Could you look up your mobile username (available at https://one.ubuntu.com/phones/) and email it to me?   martin.albisetti@canonical.com

I'll look into these issues for you.